# VHDL - SNES Interface via controller port using FPGA

Tags: vhdl, fpga, super, nintendo

I am working on trying to interface a cheap FPGA (the ep2c5t144 Altera Cyclone II mini board) with a SNES in order to ACT as a SNES controller. So far, it seems to work on and off... with the current problem being, it works for about 1 second after switched on... but then seems to get stuck in a state until it is reset.

Since I have spent a long time looking at the code for a logic issue, I'm starting to wonder whether it's some strange quirk of using FPGAs, but I've already tried testing for any states which aren't defined, and that hasn't fixed the problem. I will post the SNES code below, and the output from my cheap logic analyser which shows the problem. Warning, the code is quite messy... especially with me changing thing around to try to fix it. Any ideas at all with be much appreciated!

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Problem from logic analyser:

[When a request works - State transitions occur as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stpvT.png)

[When a request fails - SEEMS to incorrectly transition directly to "working" state and get stuck for some reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDnVW.png)

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;


entity snes_controller is
    generic (
        hp : integer := 300
    );
    port    (
        clk       : in std_logic;
        latch    : in std_logic;
        data      : out std_logic := '0';
        clock     : in std_logic;
        enable    : in std_logic;
        btn_B : in std_logic;
        btn_Y : in std_logic;
        btn_select : in std_logic;
        btn_start : in std_logic;
        btn_up : in std_logic;
        btn_down : in std_logic;
        btn_left : in std_logic;
        btn_right : in std_logic;
        btn_A : in std_logic;
        btn_X : in std_logic;
        btn_L : in std_logic;
        btn_R : in std_logic;
        helpA : out std_logic := '0';
        helpB : out std_logic := '0';
        helpC : out std_logic := '0';
        helpD : out std_logic := '0';
        helpE : out std_logic := '0'
    );
end entity;

architecture Behav of snes_controller is

    signal buttons : unsigned(16 downto 0) := "10000000000000000";

    type state_type is (s_idle, s_latching_1, s_latching_2, s_working);
    signal state : state_type := s_idle;

    type cycle_type is (c_high, c_low);
    signal cycle : cycle_type := c_high;

begin       

    process (clk)
        variable i : integer range 0 to 16;
        variable count : integer range 0 to hp;
    begin   
        if(rising_edge(clk)) then

            data <= not buttons(i);

            if(state = s_latching_1 or state = s_latching_2 or state = s_working) then
                if(count < hp) then
                    count := count+1;
                else
                    count := 0;

                    if(state = s_latching_1) then
                        if(latch = '1') then
                            state <= s_latching_2;
                            buttons(0) <= btn_B;
                            buttons(1) <= btn_Y;
                            buttons(2) <= btn_select;
                            buttons(3) <= btn_start;
                            buttons(4) <= btn_up;
                            buttons(5) <= btn_down;
                            buttons(6) <= btn_left;
                            buttons(7) <= btn_right;    
                            buttons(8) <= btn_A;
                            buttons(9) <= btn_X;
                            buttons(10) <= btn_L;
                            buttons(11) <= btn_R;
                        else
                            state <= s_idle;
                        end if;
                    elsif(state = s_latching_2) then
                        state <= s_working;
                        i := 0;
                        cycle <= c_high;
                    elsif(state = s_working) then       
                        if(latch = '1') then
                            state <= s_idle;
                            helpD <= '1';
                        elsif(cycle = c_low) then
                            cycle <= c_high;
                            if(i < 16) then
                                i := i+1;
                            else
                                state <= s_idle;
                                helpD <= '0';
                                helpE <= '0';
                            end if;
                        else
                            cycle <= c_low;
                        end if;
                    end if;

                end if;
            elsif(state = s_idle) then
                if(latch = '1') then
                    state <= s_latching_1;
                    count := 0;
                    i := 0;
                end if;
            else
                helpE <= '1';
                state <= s_idle;
                count := 0;
                i := 0;
            end if;

        end if;

    end process;

    process(state)
    begin
        if(state = s_idle) then
            helpA <= '0';
            helpB <= '0';
        elsif(state = s_latching_1) then
            helpA <= '1';
            helpB <= '0';
        elsif(state = s_latching_2) then
            helpA <= '0';
            helpB <= '1';
        elsif(state = s_working) then
            helpA <= '1';
            helpB <= '1';
        else
            helpA <= clk;
            helpB <= not clk;
        end if;

        if(cycle = c_low) then
            helpC <= '0';
        elsif(cycle = c_high) then
            helpC <= '1';
        end if;
    end process;

end Behav;
```

Comment: Your question suggests that you are not simulating your code, but are trying to debug it on the bench. It is a _much_ better idea to write a testbench and to simulate your code first. If you generate your own stimulus in a testbench, you have complete control. A simulation is reproducable. You can probe anywhere in your design easily to help you debug. You can check the behaviour of your design automatically (manual checking is too error prone). In the context of Stack Overflow, had you had a testbench, in order to help you someone else could have run your simulation to reproduce your fault.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor In this case a test bench would only work if you'd correctly simulate the asynchronicity of the inputs. I'd bet that that the answer by Oron Port is correct. The lack of synchronizers probably locks up the FSMs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using asynchronous external inputs and feed them into a synchronous, clock-based, state machine. Metastability in sampling may lead to your problem. Make sure you implement at least a two-flop synchronizer for every input signal.

Read more about it here: http://webee.technion.ac.il/~ran/papers/Metastability%20and%20Synchronizers.posted.pdf

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;


entity snes_controller is
    generic (
        hp : integer := 300
    );
    port    (
        clk       : in std_logic;
        latch    : in std_logic;
        data      : out std_logic := '0';
        clock     : in std_logic;
        enable    : in std_logic;
        btn_B : in std_logic;
        btn_Y : in std_logic;
        btn_select : in std_logic;
        btn_start : in std_logic;
        btn_up : in std_logic;
        btn_down : in std_logic;
        btn_left : in std_logic;
        btn_right : in std_logic;
        btn_A : in std_logic;
        btn_X : in std_logic;
        btn_L : in std_logic;
        btn_R : in std_logic;
        helpA : out std_logic := '0';
        helpB : out std_logic := '0';
        helpC : out std_logic := '0';
        helpD : out std_logic := '0';
        helpE : out std_logic := '0'
    );
end entity;

architecture Behav of snes_controller is

    signal synch0 : unsigned(11 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal synch1 : unsigned(11 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal synch2 : unsigned(11 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal buttons : unsigned(16 downto 0) := "10000000000000000";

    type state_type is (s_idle, s_latching_1, s_latching_2, s_working);
    signal state : state_type := s_idle;

    type cycle_type is (c_high, c_low);
    signal cycle : cycle_type := c_high;

begin       

    process (clk)
        variable i : integer range 0 to 16;
        variable count : integer range 0 to hp;
    begin   
        if(rising_edge(clk)) then
                            synch0(0) <= btn_B;
                            synch0(1) <= btn_Y;
                            synch0(2) <= btn_select;
                            synch0(3) <= btn_start;
                            synch0(4) <= btn_up;
                            synch0(5) <= btn_down;
                            synch0(6) <= btn_left;
                            synch0(7) <= btn_right;    
                            synch0(8) <= btn_A;
                            synch0(9) <= btn_X;
                            synch0(10) <= btn_L;
                            synch0(11) <= btn_R;
            synch1 <= synch0;
            synch2 <= synch1;    

            data <= not buttons(i);

            if(state = s_latching_1 or state = s_latching_2 or state = s_working) then
                if(count < hp) then
                    count := count+1;
                else
                    count := 0;

                    if(state = s_latching_1) then
                        if(latch = '1') then
                            state <= s_latching_2;
                            buttons(11 downto 0) <= synch2(11 downto 0);
                        else
                            state <= s_idle;
                        end if;
                    elsif(state = s_latching_2) then
                        state <= s_working;
                        i := 0;
                        cycle <= c_high;
                    elsif(state = s_working) then       
                        if(latch = '1') then
                            state <= s_idle;
                            helpD <= '1';
                        elsif(cycle = c_low) then
                            cycle <= c_high;
                            if(i < 16) then
                                i := i+1;
                            else
                                state <= s_idle;
                                helpD <= '0';
                                helpE <= '0';
                            end if;
                        else
                            cycle <= c_low;
                        end if;
                    end if;

                end if;
            elsif(state = s_idle) then
                if(latch = '1') then
                    state <= s_latching_1;
                    count := 0;
                    i := 0;
                end if;
            else
                helpE <= '1';
                state <= s_idle;
                count := 0;
                i := 0;
            end if;

        end if;

    end process;

    process(state)
    begin
        if(state = s_idle) then
            helpA <= '0';
            helpB <= '0';
        elsif(state = s_latching_1) then
            helpA <= '1';
            helpB <= '0';
        elsif(state = s_latching_2) then
            helpA <= '0';
            helpB <= '1';
        elsif(state = s_working) then
            helpA <= '1';
            helpB <= '1';
        else
            helpA <= clk;
            helpB <= not clk;
        end if;

        if(cycle = c_low) then
            helpC <= '0';
        elsif(cycle = c_high) then
            helpC <= '1';
        end if;
    end process;

end Behav;
```

Additionally, I suggest to create some sort of filter to handle debouncing of button clicks. http://www.eng.utah.edu/~cs5780/debouncing.pdf

Comment: Hi, you were exactly right... but it was actually the SNES' clock and latch inputs that were the problem, presumably as they were working on a separate clock which is much faster than the internal clock. The button inputs were actually fine... I should have mentioned in my previous post that the button inputs are actually controlled internally, and on the same clock, sorry! I also fixed my code to work more like a shift register... as opposed to being purely time-based from the latch. Many thanks! I'll have to read up about why adding a bunch of flip flops causes it to swing the right way now.

Comment: It is important to understand these concepts. Basically any transfer of signal between clock domains (or asynchronous to synchronous) must be properly synchronized. BTW, an upvote will be nice ;)